# appharbor connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string, appharbor

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC3 application that requires access to a database.  I've successfully set up the database on my local machine and everything works fine but then I uploaded the app to appharbor.com for testing and now I can't access the database anymore.

How do you add a connection string for a SQLEXPRESS database on appharbor.com? The database file is in located in the App_Data folder.  I've been trying for days to make it work without avail.  I already added the SQL Server add-on on appharbor.  I'm not using any Entity Framework features if it helps to know.

Comment: Have you read the [support page](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use application-embedded SQL Server express databases when running on AppHarbor. Whenever a new application version is deployed, any filesystem state is lost and you'll loose any changes to your database. Check out this guide on how to use the Sequelizer add-on: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer

Comment: Thanks friism, I'm now using Code First with automatic migration.  Everything works fine now.